# Is it possible to prevent merging PR's into a git master branch for a given period of time (say 1 hour)?

Tags: git

My company uses Git extensively, and one issue we face too often is that during a deployment PR/CR (during this period we DO NOT want anyone to merge their branch into the master branch), a PR is accidentally merged.

My question is whether or not it is possible to put some sort of preventative measure, such that no PR's can be merged into the master branch for the next hour, starting from now.

Being able to prevent PR's merging into the master branch for a given period of time.

Comment: Do you use git alone, or with GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, ...?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I use github only!

Comment: Github only wasn't (and isn't) a choice there.

Comment: Either use a pre-receive hook or take the repository offline.

Comment: If the branch is protected in GH you can temporarily add a rule that can't possibly pass.

Comment: Code freezes are rarely needed in Git, because whatever you're doing with your `master` branch could possibly be done with the desired commit on `master` instead. Some people choose to name a branch at that commit, e.g. `release` or similar.